# 'Cannot find module' Gitlab CICD pipeline on a gatsby build job

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci.yml

I'm trying to setup a CI/CD pipeline to upload my gatsby project to a server. My web page is multi language and I have a custom script that generate a JSON file for each language pulling the keys from my database. The problem is that Gitlab CICD terminates the job because it can't find the script `generatetranslateFiles.js`

The file generator script is inside a folder called translator and my npm script point to it like this and generates a folder called locales that contains each language file.

```json
"scripts": {
    "translator": "node ./translator/generatetranslateFiles.js"
  }
```

[image]

I originally had the file path like this, but same problem.

```json
"scripts": {
    "translator": "node translator/generatetranslateFiles.js"
  }
```

I also was able tu run the job locally and successfully run the script, but when deploying to the gitlab pipeline the same error appeared.

```
gitlab-runner exec shell install-job
```

This is my CICD yaml file

```yaml
image: node:16.17.0-alpine

cache:
  paths:
    - node_modules/
    - locales/

stages:
  - install
  - build

install-job:
  stage: install
  script:
    - npm install
    - npm run translator
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - node_modules
      - locales
    expire_in: 1 hour

build-job:
  stage: build
  script:
    - npm run build
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - public
    expire_in: 1 hour
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why, but instead of using `npm run` command, it worked with `node` command:

```yaml
script:
    - node translator/generatetranslateFiles.js
```